# Emacs opens gpg file without asking for passphrase

Tags: gpg, epa

I have an ASCII-armored GPG file that I open with a bookmark, and lately emacs has taken to opening it without asking for the passphrase, even if I just started emacs. I can't remember if I used symmetric encoding or my key. `epa-file-cache-passphrase-for-symmetric-encryption` is set to `nil`, `gpg-agent` isn't installed, and I don't think Gnome is caching it. So what gives? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can you be sure that GNOME is not caching the passphrase? If you are starting emacs in non-terminal mode, and if it is not asking for passphrase, you must have checked the option for "Automatically unlock whenever I am logged in".

You can start `seahorse` from the GNOME search bar or from the terminal and go to your `Gnome2 Key Storage` and search for gpg2 key passphrase and delete it from there. After that emacs should ask you for your gpg2 passphrase.

Comment: This seems to have worked - I'm embarrassed. I thought I had disabled that previously. In my defense I feel like emacs used to ask in the minibuffer, not through gnome? I couldn't see how to do it through seahorse though - I had to use `dconf-editor` as suggested in [this Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340809/how-can-i-adjust-the-default-passphrase-caching-duration-for-gpg-pgp-ssh-keys/358514#358514). Anyway thanks!

Comment: Its challenging to get .authinfo.gpg/.netrc, gpg-agent, seahorse, and emacs to all play nicely. You might check out pinentry emacs to input passphrase in the minibuffer: https://github.com/ecraven/pinentry-emacs