# Emacs not prompting for password when opening gpg file

Tags: gpg, encryption, epa

I'm trying to get started with encryption on emacs and I'm experiencing the same issue as mentioned in this question:[Emacs opens gpg file without asking for passphrase](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37002/emacs-opens-gpg-file-without-asking-for-passphrase). When I save a .gpg file, emacs prompts for the password to use, but then I can open the file (even after closing and reopening emacs) without re-entering the password. Unlike the user in the question above, there are no stored passwords in the password manager.

edit: forgot to mention that `epa-file-cache-passphrase-for-symmetric-encryption` is nil

Comment: did you check gpg-agent and epa-file-cache-passphrase-for-symmetric-encryption caching, as mentioned in the question you referred?

Answer (score 1):

For gpg version < 2, caching can be from emacs or the gpg-agent

To disable caching from emacs, set `epa-file-cache-passphrase-for-symmetric-encryption` to nil if it is not nil in emacs config file

`(setq epa-file-cache-passphrase-for-symmetric-encryption nil)`

To disable caching by gpg-agent, add
`default-cache-ttl 0` to  gpg config file located at `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`

For gpg version >= 2, disabling gpg-agent cache would suffice.
So just add `default-cache-ttl 0` to  gpg config file located at `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`